# Is there a way to identify the start of Linux's signal handling using systems like Sysdig?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

I am learning about Linux signal handling.

I am auditing an application (using Sysdig) while it runs. The application can receive different signals at any time and it defines various signal handlers for different signals. I am wondering if there is a reliable way by looking at the output of system audit logs to know when the application received a signal?

For example, I think I can reliably tell that a signal is finished when I see the `RT_SIGRETURN` system call in the log.

Comment: Can you modify the application? Or just observe it?

Comment: I can only observe it dynamically as it runs.